# Ubuntu 21.10 freezes after plugging a seconds monitor

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor

I installed ubuntu 21.10 on a new SSD drive i have bought, it's has been working well so far, out of the sudden it freezes when I plug my second monitor through HDMI which used to work fine, I suspect this issue has started after I installed Nvidia software 440 i believe, and set it as "High performance" so i can my high resolutions games.

I tried to downgrade the Nvidia driver to 390, no avail.
I changed the Nvidia resolution to "Medium" and even selected the Intel integrated video card to see if it makes difference, now the second monitor doesn't freeze my ubuntu but it's no longer detected ever.

I am pretty sure this issue has something to do with the Nvidia driver after high resolution setting.

I have a Windows 10 on my first HDD drive and works fine with secondary screen no problem at all

I hope you can give give me an adivce how i can make my second monitor work find as my Windows 10 and play my games with Nvidia high resolution.

Thank you,

Comment: Nvidia driver version 390/440 is old. Go `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab, and see if there's something newer/supported there, or go to https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/ and get yourself the latest driver for your specific video card. Report back.

Comment: Hello...
Got the same/similar issue.
As far I was able to find is an issue with the kernel bug.
This issue is happening only ( as fas I was for me ) to people with intel GPU
I have a Lenovo Yoga c740 with only Intel CometLake-U GT2 UHD
Since the Intel GPU going through kernel this was reported to ubuntu as a kernel bug.

Comment: Here is a pic of the monitor: https://ibb.co/ZVybnt6
One of way to solve it is to downgrade to the kernel that was used in ubuntu 20.01. 
I'm also a bit crazy since the issue can f*** up your work when random freeze
At first, I thought it was my GPU broken.